# How to get network Log without using selenium

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, networking

I want to get the network traffic without using selenium.I am making an android app a small part of its function is to obtain the network urls select specific links and send http request to those links for futher working...

[Picture of network traffic in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPKrf.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `BrowserMobProxy`. By using this in your code, you will get a `.har` file at the end of your execution which will provide you all the network traffic captured during the execution. You can view this file in a online `.har` viewer.

[BrowserMobProxy: get started](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/browsermob-proxy-selenium-example)

Comment: Will this work on android ? as i want to retrieve few of the links as string and execute them further?

Comment: Have personally tried it on `Chrome`. Don't know about `Android`.